# Syntax error in ternary if-else statement

Tags: python, conditional-operator

We can use if-else like this:

```
statement if condition else statement
```

but there are some problems here and I can't understand why.

1. If I run `count += 1 if True else l = []` (count is defined already), then it raises an error:

   ```
    File "<ipython-input-5-d65dfb3e9f1c>", line 1
    count += 1 if True else l = []
                              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
   ```

   Can we not assign a value after else?
2. When I run `count += 1 if False else l.append(count+1)` (note: count = 0, l = []), an error will be raised:

   ```
    TypeError    Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-38-84cb28b02a03> in <module>()
    ----> 1 count += 1 if False else l.append(count+1)

    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'
   ```

   and the result of l is `[1]`.

Using the same conditions, if I use an if-else block, there are no errors.

Can you explain the difference?

Comment: `... if ... else ...` is not a shorthand/one-line `if ...: ... else: ...`, but something entirely different.

Comment: Related: [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](//stackoverflow.com/q/394809) (The accepted answer actually explains the reason for this error)

Comment: `x if y else z` is requires *expressions*, and you provide it an augmented assignment *statement*. Your fundamental misunderstanding is that it takes the form `statement if condition else statement`, rather it should always be `<expression> if <expression> else <expression>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "conditional expression" [`A if C else B`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) is not a one-line version of the if/else statement [`if C: A; else: B`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement), but something entirely different. The first will evaluate the *expressions* `A` or `B` and then return the result, whereas the latter will just execute either of the *statements* `A` or `B`.

More clearly, `count += 1 if True else l = []` is *not* `(count += 1) if True else (l = [])`, but `count += (1 if True else l = [])`, but `l = []` is not an expression, hence the syntax error.

Likewise, `count += 1 if False else l.append(count+1)` is not `(count += 1) if False else (l.append(count+1))` but `count += (1 if False else l.append(count+1))`. Syntactically, this is okay, but `append` returns `None`, which can not be added to `count`, hence the TypeError.

Answer (score 5):

For your first error, you are trying to misuse a ternary expression. In Python, ternary expressions cannot contain *statements* they contain **expressions**.

As can be seen [in Python's official grammar](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Grammar/Grammar), an assignment is a **statement**, and a method call is an **expression**.

In your samples, `l = []` is considered a statement, whereas `l.append(...)` is an expression.

For your second error, `list.append` returns `None`, not the list. Therefore, you are essentially trying to add `None` to either an integer, which is not permitted, hence the `TypeError`.

Lastly, please don't use the lowercase L's (`l`) or uppercase o's (`O`) as variable names. As stated in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id38), these can be extremely confusing variable names due to their similarity to 1's and 0's.

Answer (score 2):

The one-line `if-else` statement in python is more like the ternary operator in other languages. It is not just a more compact version of an `if-else` block. The one-line `if-else` evaluates to a value, while the `if-else` block specifies conditions under which different actions should be taken. The single-line `if-else` statement is like a function that returns one value under some condition and another value if the condition is `False`.

So in your example, when you write `count += 1 if True else l = []`, what i think you mean is:

```
if True:
    count += 1
else:
    l = []
```

But what this line is really doing is something like:

```
if True:
    count += 1
else:
    count += l = []
```

Hence the syntax error.