# Syntax Error in Inline if … else Syntax in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, syntax-error

What exactly is wrong with the syntax and why in the following piece of code?
I've counted the parentheses among other things yet am unable to figure it out.

```
c = ""
 print("Yes") if c else print("No")
```

Note: It gives a Syntax error like the one below:

```
print("Yes") if c else print("No")
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: it works for me.... take a look at your indentation

Comment: @B001ᛦ How does it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error in if else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342536/syntax-error-in-if-else-statement)

Comment: `print` is a statement in python 2. You can't use statements in a conditional.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write inline if statement for print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880430/how-to-write-inline-if-statement-for-print)

Comment: in Python 2 `print "Yes" if c else "No"`

Comment: @Psytho I don't  know  _how_ it works but it works fine

Comment: @B001ᛦ Do you run it on Python 2.7?

Comment: @B001ᛦ It works in Python 3 only

Comment: @Psytho no in 3.6.5... my bad...didnt get OP was asking for 2.7

Answer (score 4):

This happens because the `print` function behaves differently in python2 and python3:
Meanwhile in python3 your code works perfectly, in python2 it raises an error.
This happens because in python2, `print` is actually a [statement](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html#the-print-function) and not a function; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-python) you can find a more in-depth QA on the difference between functions and statements.

By the way, you can solve your problem importing the python3 print function from the *future*:

```
from __future__ import print_function

c = ""

print("Yes") if c else print("No")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
No
```