# Ternary Operator SyntaxError

Tags: python

I am trying to practice using ternary operators and I want to use them to set a value to False or True, but I am getting an error. Do you guys know what I am doing wrong?

`play = False if ans.lower() is 'n' else play = True`

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-python)

Comment: try `play = False if ans.lower() is 'n' else True`

Comment: Although that's the same as `play = ans.lower() is 'n'`, so the ternary operator is of not much use here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax error in ternary if-else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342536/syntax-error-in-ternary-if-else-statement)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your immediate problem with:

```
play = False if ans.lower() is 'n' else True
```

*without* the extra assignment after the `else`. The basic idea of the ternary is:

```
finalValue = valueOne if someCondition else valueTwo
```

However, there are other problems with that<sup>(1)</sup>, so I'd suggest the more succinct:

```
play = (ans.lower() != 'n')
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Amongst them the fact that `is` checks for *identity* equality, not *value* equality. See, for example:

```
>>> x = 9999
>>> y = 9999
>>> x == y
True
>>> x is y
False
```

You'll notice that the two objects are distinct even though they have the same value.

Secondly, you don't actually *need* a ternary if you're using a boolean value to feed into it, you can just use the boolean operators to manipulate it.

Any ternary of the forms:

```
True if condition else False
False if condition else True
```

can be better espressed as (respectively):

```
condition
not condition
```

Comment: `condition` instead of a ternary may not always be sufficient - e.g. consider `sum(x for x in X if x)` vs `sum(bool(x) for for x in X)`